# Page Specific JavaScript Function on Several Files of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have about 10 pages of HTML and each has a link to `indexJS.js`. I have a function `loadMoreOnScroll()` in the js file that is meant to run only for my `index.html`. But the `loadMoreOnScroll()` is run on all the pages as users scroll to the bottom.

How do I restrict `loadMoreOnScroll()` to only run for `index.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add classes to distinguish pages.

```
<body class="index">...
```

And with JavaScript:

```
if(document.body.className.match(/\bindex\b/)){
    // code
}
```

of jQuery:

```
if($("body").hasClass("index")){
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the `body` tag on the index then in javascript you can do something like

```
if(document.querySelector('body').className === 'myclass'){
 loadMoreOnScroll();
}
```

Note: this assumes you have no other classes on the body. You could use a data attribute and do `getAttribute('data-page')` or something to similar effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the loadMoreOnScroll() function from indexJS and create a new JavaSscript file with loadMoreOnScroll() in it. Be sure to include a reference to the new file in the index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're invoking `loadMoreOnScroll` from within your `indexJS.js` file, correct?

If so, the solution is to remove the function call from your javascript file and instead call it directly from  index.html.

**indexJS.js**

```
// Create the function but don't call it here
function loadMoreOnScroll(){...}
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="indexJS.js></script>
<script>
    // call the function
    loadMoreOnScroll();
</script>
```

Edit:

A few other people suggested adding a body class and targeting your page that way. This approach is fine, and may work well in many scenarios but just keep in mind two things:

1. This works well for if you need to call your function on only one or two pages. Any more and you'll have to maintain a growing list of body classes within `indexJS.js`.
2. Using the body class as a hook decouples the function call from the page that its applies to.

In other words, the body class will have functionality tied to it that's not immediately obvious if you're only looking at the HTML. If you're working on the code yourself, you'll probably be ok, but in a team environment, it could be error-prone. (Or if you revisit the code after a few months). It all depends on the scope of your project.